# Fire Checked and unchecked event DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate - DataTemplate checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

is it possible to only fire an event in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate

The code below will not fire when I check and uncheck the checkbox..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Unchecked="Event" Checked="Event" IsChecked="{Binding Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

However, it will with DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Unchecked="Event" Checked="Event" IsChecked="{Binding Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But this causes the event to fire on view load which causes problems in the backend. I only want the event to fire in edit mode, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Put `ClickMode="Press"` on your `CheckBox`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Checked & Unchecked event, you can use the clicked event of the CheckBox and then get checked state from the event handler

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TestBool}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;
}
```